# unpacking a column of a list of pairs into two columns - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe
df:

```
ID   li
ld1  [1205369-1205491, 1206384-1206570]
ld2  [111-112,113-114,117-119]
ld3  [444-445,765-785,777-779]
ld5  [1203843-1203967, 1204033-1204235, 1204398-1204485]
ld28 [666-777,756-788,896-909]
ld37 [999-1000,1001-1111,1112-1119,1234-1278,1999-2007]
```

I want to split this column of lists (li) into two columns start and end positions of pairs where the start column will have all start positions and the end column will have all end positions separated by','

Desired result:

```
ID     start                    end
ld1   1205369,1206384           1205491,1206570
ld2   111,113,117               112,114,119
ld3   444,765,777               445,785,779
ld5   1203843,1204033,1204398   1203967,1204235,1204485
ld28  666,756,896               777,788,909
ld37  999,1001,1112,1234,1999   1000,1111,1119,1278,2007
```

Comment: Is `444=445` a typo or part of the data?

Comment: yes..sorry for the typo error, it should be '-' only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way using `.explode` and `.str.split` followed by `join`

assuming `=` was a typo? but we can handle it with a `str.replace`

```
df1 = df.join(df['li'].str.replace('=','-').str.split(',')\
             .explode().str.split('-',expand=True)\
             .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)\
             .rename(columns={0 : 'start', 1 : 'end'})).drop('li',axis=1)


print(df1)

     ID                      start                       end
0   ld1           1205369, 1206384           1205491,1206570
1   ld2                111,113,117               112,114,119
2   ld3                444,765,777               445,785,779
3   ld5  1203843, 1204033, 1204398   1203967,1204235,1204485
4  ld28                666,756,896               777,788,909
5  ld37    999,1001,1112,1234,1999  1000,1111,1119,1278,2007
```

Comment: +1, we had the same idea. (I swear I did not peek!) I think I'll still leave my answer as the steps are arranged in a slightly different way.

Comment: @fsimonjetz only diff is that you'rs doesn't have the row with `=` as the separator =)

Comment: Yeah, I glossed over that. I think assigning the result to `df` with `df[['start', 'end']] = ...`  is a bit more readable than renaming the columns inline. But perhaps that's more of a comment than an answer of its own.

Comment: @Umar.H thats a typo error it should be '-' only

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with `split` and then join back is first idea:

```
df[['start', 'end']] = (df.pop('li')
                          .explode()
                          .str.split('-', expand=True)
                          .groupby(level=0)
                          .agg(','.join))
print (df)
     ID                    start                       end
0   ld1          1205369,1206384           1205491,1206570
1   ld2              111,113,117               112,114,119
2   ld3              444,765,777               445,785,779
3   ld5  1203843,1204033,1204398   1203967,1204235,1204485
4  ld28              666,756,896               777,788,909
5  ld37  999,1001,1112,1234,1999  1000,1111,1119,1278,2007
```

Or use list comprehension with split and `join` with `zip`:

```
L = [[','.join(z) for z in zip(*[y.split('-') for y in x])] for x in df.pop('li')]
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['start', 'end'], index=df.index))
print (df)
     ID                    start                       end
0   ld1          1205369,1206384           1205491,1206570
1   ld2              111,113,117               112,114,119
2   ld3              444,765,777               445,785,779
3   ld5  1203843,1204033,1204398   1203967,1204235,1204485
4  ld28              666,756,896               777,788,909
5  ld37  999,1001,1112,1234,1999  1000,1111,1119,1278,2007
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
import re

df2 = pd.DataFrame([list(map(list, zip(*(re.split(r'[-=]', x) for x in l))))
                    for l in df['li']],
                   columns=['start', 'end'], index=df.index)

df.drop(columns='li').join(df2)
```

Output:

```
     ID                          start                             end
0   ld1            [1205369,  1206384]              [1205491, 1206570]
1   ld2                [111, 113, 117]                 [112, 114, 119]
2   ld3                [444, 765, 777]                 [445, 785, 779]
3   ld5  [1203843,  1204033,  1204398]     [1203967, 1204235, 1204485]
4  ld28                [666, 756, 896]                 [777, 788, 909]
5  ld37  [999, 1001, 1112, 1234, 1999]  [1000, 1111, 1119, 1278, 2007]
```

For in place modification:

```
import re

df[['start', 'end']] = [list(map(list, zip(*(re.split(r'[-=]', x) for x in l))))
                        for l in df.pop('li')]
```